# P5 javascript LoadJSON Data is to late

Tags: javascript, json, p5.js

I've tried to read a Json file with loadJSON from p5 but the data comes to late. If I try `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` it says `{}`.

```
function setup() {
    for(i = 0;i <= 3;i++) {

        //load the JSON
        data = loadJSON('test'+ i +'.json');

        //Work with it
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data);
   }
}
```

Comment: can you post the code that is giving you this issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: _"This method is **asynchronous**, meaning it may **not finish** before the **next** line in your sketch is executed..."_ ([Reference](http://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadJSON)) - You need to read the docs and use a callback function as explained in the duplicate

Comment: Ds = loadJSON('test' + 1 + '.json');
delay().then(function(tt){
 console.log(Ds);
 console.log(date);
})                                                                                                                              Dosn't work in a loop?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function test(mynewdata) {
    console.log(mynewdata);
}

data = loadJSON('test' + i + '.json',test);
```

This works for me. Thanks!

Comment: Note that you can mark this answer as accepted so your question stops showing up as still needing an answer.